# Recomendation for code spliting to multiple files HTML/JS

Tags: html, jquery, import, menu, load

I'd like to split my code to multiple files. I've just finished vertical menu and curently it's in `index.html`. I'd like create new folder called **Menu** and inside `menu.html` and `menu.js.` I use only HTML/JS and also CSS

**menu.js**

```
<div class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <header>
        <div class="close-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <img
          src="#"
          alt="Logo"
        />
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>Dashboard</a>
            <div class="item">
              <a class="sub-btn"
                ><i class="fas fa-table"></i>Matematika<i
                  class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"
                ></i
              ></a>
              <div class="sub-menu">
                <a href="/pages/matematika1.html" class="sub-item"
                  >Matematika#1</a
                >
                <a href="" class="sub-item">Matematika#2</a>
                <a href="" class="sub-item">Matematika#3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Forms</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
```

**menu.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //jquery for toggle sub menus
        $(".sub-btn").click(function () {
          $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
          $(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("rotate");
        });

        //jquery for expand and collapse the sidebar
        $(".menu-btn").click(function () {
          $(".side-bar").addClass("active");
          $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "hidden");
        });

        $(".close-btn").click(function () {
          $(".side-bar").removeClass("active");
          $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "visible");
        });
      });
```

Also first step is necessary import the script file to html file. I can do it via `<script src="menu.js" type="module"></script>`

Second step i must somehow include `menu.html` in `index.html`. I tried some jquery **.load function** but i think there must be something more simple than using Jquery for that. Also tried manuel by [jotform](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-imports-import-html-files-into-html-files-83467/) but i'm not enough skilled to understand that cuz it's not working for me

Best

Comment: Do you use any scripting language or UI framework? Like PhP, python etc?

Comment: Ou sorry i forgot to tell it. I use HTML/JS and also CSS. Already updated above

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any frameworks, you'd better use [web components](https://opensource.com/article/21/7/web-components) for splitting your code.